# Using querySelector in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

`querySelector` returns `null`(maybe because element is not created) , I tried event `DOMContentLoaded` and `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`

```
const Header = () => {
  const links = document.querySelector('.header_links')
    window.addEventListener('resize',() => {
      if(window.innerWidth <=1000 ){
        links.classList.remove('hide');
      }
    })
  return (
      <header className="App-header">
        <div className="inner-header">
          <div className="header_links">
          <div className="header_left_links">
            <a href="index.html" className="active">DrukBox</a>
            <a href="printfile.html">Print File</a>
            <a href="history.html">History</a>
            <a href="addpages.html">Add pages</a>
          </div>
          <div className="header_right_links">
            <a href="/">Sign in</a>
          </div>
          </div>
          <BurgerMenu />
        </div>
      </header>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't see an element with class `header-links` in your JSX. And try to use hook `useRef` instead of `querySelector `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `dash(-)` instead of `underscore(_)`.

You html JSX contains underscore.

```
<div className="header_links">
```

while your `querySelector` contains dash.

```
const links = document.querySelector('.header-links')
```

Modify it to `underscore`.

Also I agree with @Alexandr, to you `useRef` if possible.

```
const Header = () => {
  const refHeaderLink = useRef(null);
  
    window.addEventListener('resize',() => {
      if(window.innerWidth <=1000 ){
        refHeaderLink.current.classList.remove('hide');
      }
    })
  return (
      <header className="App-header">
        <div className="inner-header">
          <div className="header_links" ref={refHeaderLink}>
          <div className="header_left_links">
            <a href="index.html" className="active">DrukBox</a>
            <a href="printfile.html">Print File</a>
            <a href="history.html">History</a>
            <a href="addpages.html">Add pages</a>
          </div>
          <div className="header_right_links">
            <a href="/">Sign in</a>
          </div>
          </div>
          <BurgerMenu />
        </div>
      </header>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited dash to underscore but it didnt solve my problem

Comment: @Alexandr, also i'm just a beginner in this, if anything is wrong, you're welcome to edit the answer.

Comment: @JitendraYadav Only one thing is critical in your code: every render of the `Header` component will add a new event listener. You should clean up excess ones. See docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use state without refs.

```
const Header = () => {
  const [isHiddenLinks, setIsHiddenLink] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      if (window.innerWidth <= 1000) {
        setIsHiddenLink(false);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, [isHiddenLinks]);

  return (
    <header className="App-header">
      <div className="inner-header">
        <div className={`header_links ${isHiddenLinks ? "hide" : ""}`}>
          <div className="header_left_links">
            <a href="index.html" className="active">
              DrukBox
            </a>
            <a href="printfile.html">Print File</a>
            <a href="history.html">History</a>
            <a href="addpages.html">Add pages</a>
          </div>
          <div className="header_right_links">
            <a href="/">Sign in</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <BurgerMenu />
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};
```

Comment: And don't forget to add `removeEventListener`

Comment: Thanx but i completely dont know how it works((( i need to read documentation

Comment: It is normal! But read documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup and try to understand.

Good luck with your studies! ;-)